# Saving base64 image using useState fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo, use-state

The attempt to save `base64` image by calling `setImage` and `useEffect` to reflect the change fails. The `base64` image saved to `useState` needs to be passed using  `navigation.navigate`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

index.js

```
function Homes({navigation,route}) {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    (async () => {
      if (Platform.OS !== 'web') {
        const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
        }
      }
    }); 
  }, [image]);

  const ImagePick= async () => {
    try{
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    console.log(result); //see the result below
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImage(result); 
    }    
    console.log(image); //does not change. Still Null.
    // navigation.navigate('User',{image: image})
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error);
  };
}
return (
<TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => {
          ImagePick();
        {image &&  navigation.navigate('User',{image: image})}
        }}
        style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>upload</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
);
}
```

The information of **console.log(result);**
[image]

Comment: `image` is a local `const`. Calling `setImage` can not change it, it can only request that the component be rerendered, so the log statement on the next lines can't show a changed value. In your case, i would recommend you use the `result` variable to do your navigation, as in `navigation.navigate('User', {image: result})`. If you only want to do that when result.cancelled is false, you can put that code inside the if block

Comment: And in your effect:  `(async () => { ... })` declares an async function but it is never called.